# bootstrap3 - toggle class name by @media

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, toggle, twitter-bootstrap-3

i search for a class toggle which switches by changing the resolution. 
in my case when the resolution changes to @screen-lg **or** @screen-md - the class should toggle to **btn-lg**

**@screen-sm** (standart)

```
<a class = "btn btn-default btn-sm">Button</a>
```

**@screen-lg** or **@screen-md** (toggle)

```
<a class = "btn btn-default btn-lg">Button</a>
```

i think a solution is using jquery, but i need a little help for this. 
Please can anybody help me. 
or is there a solution which is much more easyier?

thx

Comment: Could you describe the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same breakpoints that Bootstrap uses for its media queries to change the size of your button:

```
/*Default state (btn-sm styles)*/
.btn {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
/*md or lg screen (btn-lg styles)*/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .btn {
        padding: 10px 16px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.33;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
}
```

Note: The example above would apply the behavior to all `.btn` elements, you can use a custom class if you want to limit your selection

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/yNnuU/1/)**